# How to get OrientDB Server Side OGlobalConfiguration on orientdb client?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

I am trying to get all the OrientDB Server Side OGlobalConfiguration on orientdb client using java code. Is it possible using java API, as I am not able to find the correct API?

For e.g. I have configured property `<entry name="network.token.expireTimeout" value="120"/>` in orientdb-server-config.xml, but when I do `oDatabaseSession.getConfiguration().getValue(OGlobalConfiguration.NETWORK_TOKEN_EXPIRE_TIMEOUT)` I still get default value as 60.

Can we get server side configuration on client side? or both are different?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use method `com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OrientDBRemote#getServerInfo`, which you, in turn, can get when you open a connection to the server using `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDB` .